# Building a Android application for website developed in JSP and MySQL

Tags: android, jsp, webview, web

I am developing basic android applications. I am doing a BE project on web application which is a resort management portal. I will be giving Room booking, cancellation and lots of services using JSP..

For addition, I would like to prepare an Android application from which user will be able to book rooms (it will be a registration form and later data will be sent to JSP page) again, there should be page for room booking status update too..

I know, we can use webview to view webpages in android but does it need any specific layout of an webpage?

I am bit confused..

Answer (score 0):

Your layout needs to be mobile optimized, that is you need to consider the resolution of the devices consider the user experience for mobile device. For a very good example, check out gmail in Mobile vs. the one in desktop or even stackoverflow in both desktop and mobile. They both provide same functionality but have their own mobile optimized layout.

Additionally, in building the webpages, you would want to consider Javascript Framework that is optimized for touch such as [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) or [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: Is there any free / open source framework available for mobile website for touch interface?

Comment: Both jQueryMobile and jQTouch are free for you to use